# Python List Append with bumpy array error

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use list append function to append a list to a list.

But got error shows list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. Not sure why.

```
pca_components = range(1,51)
gmm_components = range(1,5)
covariance_types = ['spherical', 'diag', 'tied', 'full']

# Spherical
spherical_results = []
for i in pca_components:
    pca_model = PCA(n_components=i)
    pca_train = pca_model.fit(train_data).transform(train_data)
    for j in gmm_components:
        parameters = (i+i)*j*2
        if parameters > 50:
            pass
        else:             
            gmm_model = GMM(n_components=j, covariance_type='spherical')
            gmm_model.fit(pca_train)
            pca_test = pca_model.transform(test_data)
            predictions = gmm_model.predict(pca_test)
            accuracy = np.mean(predictions.ravel() == test_labels.ravel())
            accuracy=int(accuracy)
            spherical_results.append([accuracy, i,j, parameters])
spher_results = np.array(spherical_results)
max_accuracy = np.amax(spherical_results[:,0])
print(f"highest accuracy score for spherical is {max_accuracy}")
```

Comment: `spherical_results` is a *python `list` object*. You tried to index into it with a `tuple`, : `spherical_results[:,0]`. But as the error message explains, `list` objects do not support this. You probably meant `spher_results`. Try to use more distinctive variable names

Comment: I think what you want is extend and not append. Append adds primitive data type at the last index while extend as it says extends the list with another list.

Comment: @PriyankMehta um, no. `.append` adds **any** object, including a list object. There *are no primitive data types in Python*.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a bumpy array, or did you just mispell numpy?

Comment: @PriyankMehta. To put it another way, `append` accepts any object and adds it as a single list element, while `extend` requires an iterable, each of whose elements becomes an individual list element.

Comment: @user3483203. A bumpy array is one that is neither monitonically increasing nor decreasing. The bumpiness is measured in terms of how many local maxima it has :)

Comment: @user3483203. I think it's just a typo.

Comment: Also, as an aside, `int(accuracy)` is very suspect. Accuracy usually will be defined on the interval `[0,1]`. In which case, calling `int` on it will give you 0 unless the accuracy is 1 (in which case you get 1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of this line?

```
spher_results = np.array(spherical_results)
```

It makes an array from a list.  But you don't use `spher_results` in the following code.

Comment: Hi Hpaulj, good call,  actually that is the reason why I got error.  I just fixed with sperical_results=np.array(shperical_results)